# Find and replace string within string

Tags: vb.net

I want to check whether within particular string exist **two** brackets `()`. Starting and ending bracket.

```
Dim example1 = "1x : (HxBxT) 80x120x44 cm"
Dim example2 = "1x : ( 80x120x44 cm"
```

In this case example1 contains both brackets: ( and closing one ) therefore it passed the case.
In this case i would like to take entire value in this case `(HxBxT)` and then replace it by something (i will do that). After that i would like insert replace again so for instance at the end i would get this:

```
Dim example1 = "1x : (whatever i put here) 80x120x44 cm"
```

Comment: And example2 is invalid so you won't replace it?

Comment: Use regular expression `\(.*\)` within [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
example1 = Regex.Replace(example1, "\(.*\)", "(whatever i put here)")
```

If you just want to know if there are opening anc closing brackets you can either use regex:

```
Dim containsBrackets = Regex.IsMatch(example1, "\(.*\)")
```

or the VB.NET [`Like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator):

```
Dim containsBrackets = example1 like "*(*)*"
```

or `String.IndexOf`:

```
Dim indexOfOpeningBracket =  example1.IndexOf("(")
Dim indexOfClosingBracket =  example1.IndexOf(")", indexOfOpeningBracket + 1)
Dim containsBrackets = indexOfOpeningBracket >= 0 AndAlso indexOfClosingBracket > 0
```

This also enables you to get the part between the parentheses with `Substring`:

```
If containsBrackets
   indexOfOpeningBracket += 1 ' you dont want the parentheses itself but just the content
   Dim partBetween = example1.Substring(indexOfOpeningBracket, indexOfClosingBracket - indexOfOpeningBracket)
End If
```

Comment: is there a way to firstly check to get yes/no as boolean if () are there and then extract this string and after that do something with it and then replace? More steps but is it possible>

Comment: @Tony: i have shown you 3 different ways to get this `Boolean`. You also want to extract the old substring between the parentheses?

Comment: thx and how to get text itself inluding bracets to some variable?

Comment: @Tony: then don't add 1 to `indexOfOpeningBracket`, so remove this line. But add 1 to the length, the second parameter of `Substring`: `example1.Substring(indexOfOpeningBracket, indexOfClosingBracket - indexOfOpeningBracket + 1)`. Of course you could also use `"(" & partBetween & ")"`

Comment: great and if i want brackets? I will mark as answer.

Comment: @Tony: try to find it out yourself, you now know everything you need

Comment: just tell me why you did this: ? indexOfOpeningBracket += 1

Comment: @Tony: to start the Substring after the opening parenthesis. `IndexOf` returns the index of a substring **before** it starts, so without `+=` the substring would contains the opening parenthesis. Since i wanted to omit them and only extract the content i have added 1. Play around with it and you will understand

Comment: i tried to do it with bracets but i get strange results:  Dim partBetwee2n = example1.Substring(indexOfOpeningBracket , indexOfClosingBracket)

Comment: @Tony: the second parameter is the length not the end index. You haven't used my code

Comment: dont know how to do that  tried to remove -indexOfOpeningBracket .. ;/

Comment: Why you have removed it? It is needed to calculate the correct length of the substring

Comment: @Tony: haven't i showed you already the [different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922314/find-and-replace-string-within-string/47922483?noredirect=1#comment82818307_47922483)? I think i'm talking to a wall :)

Comment: not sure but this works:             Dim partBetrrween = example1.Substring(indexOfOpeningBracket -1, indexOfClosingBracket - indexOfOpeningBracket + 2) is this correct?

Comment: Isn't it easier and more readable to use the approach that i have mentioned in my earlier comment which i have again added as link in my last comment? You have several ways, for example: 1) don't add 1 to `indexOfOpeningBracket`, so remove this line. But add 1 to the length which is the second parameter of `String.Substring`. So like here: `example1.Substring(indexOfOpeningBracket, indexOfClosingBracket - indexOfOpeningBracket + 1`. 2) You could also use the code in my answer which is the part beween brackets and then wrap it again in brackets afterwards: "(" & partBetween & ")"

Comment: @tony. Read the dcoumentation of [`String.Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) and play with the results to get familiar with it.

Comment: i read seems what ive done is right way and it works what do you think?: Dim partBetrrween = example1.Substring(indexOfOpeningBracket -1, indexOfClosingBracket - indexOfOpeningBracket + 2)

Answer (score 0):

you can take help of indexOf method like this

```
Dim openBracket = myText.IndexOf("(")
Dim closeBracket = myText.IndexOf(")")
```

if any of openBracket and closeBracket is -1(meaning not found) your case is failed if both are 0 or >0 this means you case pass

then you can use subString method like this to get your string

```
Dim lenStr = openBracket + closeBracket + 1
dim repStr = myText.Substring(startIndex, lenStr)
dim newString = myText.Replace(repStr,"Whatever text you want to put here)"
```

I do not have access to VB.net so my syntax may be a little off but this will give you idea

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use Regex, you can try this:

```
Dim str As String = "1x : (HxBxT) 80x120x44 cm"
Dim newValue As String = "whatever i put here"
If str Like "*(*)*" Then
    str = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                        Strings.Left(str, str.IndexOf("("c) + 1),
                        newValue,
                        Strings.Right(str, str.Length - str.IndexOf(")"c)))
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions within [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

```
Dim input As String = "x : (HxBxT) 80x120x44 cm" 
Dim pattern As String = "\(.*\)"
Dim replacement As String = "(whatever i put here)"
Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)
```